# How to create the next file or folder in a series of progressively numbered files?

Tags: perl, filenames

Sorry for the bad title but this is the best I could do! :D

I have a script which creates a new project every time the specified function is called.

Each project must be stored in its own folder, with the name of the project. But, if you don't specify a name, the script will just name it "new projectX", where X is a progressive number.

With time the user could rename the folders or delete some, so every time the script runs, it checks for the smallest number available (not used by another folder) and creates the relevant folder.

Now I managed to make a program which I think works as wanted, but I would like to hear from you if it's OK or there's something wrong which I'm unable to spot, given my inexperience with the language.

```
    while ( defined( $file = readdir $projects_dir ) )
    {
        # check for files whose name start with "new project"
        if ( $file =~ m/^new project/i )
        {
            push( @files, $file );
        }
    }

    # remove letters from filenames, only the number is left
    foreach $file ( @files )
    {
        $file =~ s/[a-z]//ig;
    }

    @files = sort { $a <=> $b } @files;

    # find the smallest number available
    my $smallest_number = 0;

    foreach $file ( @files )
    {
        if ( $smallest_number != $file )
        {
            last;
        }
        $smallest_number += 1;
    }

    print "Smallest number is $smallest_number";
```

Comment: TOCTOU - Time of Check, Time of Use.  How many copies of this code will be running in parallel?  Do you retry if the first attempt fails with 'directory exists'?

Comment: What about: `last if ($smallest_number != $file);` instead of 4 lines?

Comment: `$file =~ s/[a-z]//ig;` does not remove the blank in `new project` (though blank followed by number probably converts to a number OK).

Comment: Why not simply keep the 'last number used' and not worry about reusing previously used numbers.  You can do a synchronized (multi-process safe) update of a file containing the last used number, to give your code a new number that no other process should use.  Contiguity of numbers is seldom really necessary; it takes a while to get through even 1 million projects, let alone 10 million or 100 million.

Comment: @Jonathan: thanks for the code hints, I'm not practice with the Perl syntax so I tend to write more like C. I thought about using a "last number" index, but I wanted to try this approach to test myself with this new language. Seems like I will learn many new things with your comments :)

Comment: Pad with the number with zeros using, e.g., `sprintf ("%0.4d",$n)` to ensure that sorting by text would also sort by numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would use something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new_project_dir
{
    my($base) = @_;
    opendir(my $dh, $base) || die "Failed to open directory $base for reading";
    my $file;
    my @numbers;
    while ($file = readdir $dh)
    {
        $numbers[$1] = 1 if ($file =~ m/^new project(\d+)$/)
    }
    closedir($dh) || die "Failed to close directory $base";
    my $i;
    my $max = $#numbers;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
    {
        next if (defined $numbers[$i]);
        # Directory did not exist when we scanned the directory
        # But maybe it was created since then!
        my $dir = "new project$i";
        next unless mkdir "$base/$dir";
        return $dir;
    }
    # All numbers from 0..$max were in use...so try adding new numbers...
    while ($i < $max + 100)
    {
        my $dir = "new project$i";
        $i++;
        next unless mkdir "$base/$dir";
        return $dir;
    }
    # Still failed - give in...
    die "Something is amiss - all directories 0..$i in use?";
}
```

Test code:

```
my $basedir = "base";
mkdir $basedir unless -d $basedir;

for (my $j = 0; $j < 10; $j++)
{
    my $dir = new_project_dir($basedir);
    print "Create: $dir\n";
    if ($j % 3 == 2)
    {
        my $k = int($j / 2);
        my $o = "new project$k";
        rmdir "$basedir/$o";
        print "Remove: $o\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach because of the attention to the various problems that may occur, I learned a lot of things with just an answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a basic approach for this sort of problem:

```
sub next_available_dir {
    my $n = 1;
    my $d;
    $n ++ while -e ($d = "new project$n");
    return $d;
}

my $project_dir = next_available_dir();
mkdir $project_dir;
```

If you're willing to use a naming pattern that plays nicely with Perl's [string auto-increment feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement), you can simplify the code further, eliminating the need for `$n`. For example, `newproject000`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong per se, but that's an awful lot of code to achieve a single objective (get the minimum index of directories.

A core module, couple of subs and few Schwartzian transforms will make the code more flexible:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'min';

sub num { $_[0] =~ s|\D+||g } # 'new project4' -> '4', 'new1_project4' -> '14' (!)

sub min_index {

    my ( $dir, $filter ) = @_;

    $filter = qr/./ unless defined $filter; # match all if no filter specified

    opendir my $dirHandle, $dir or die $!;

    my $lowest_index = min                 # get the smallest ...
                        map  { num($_)   }  # ... numerical value ...
                         grep {    -d     }  # ... from all directories ...
                          grep { /$filter/ }  # ... that match the filter ...
                           readdir $dirHandle; # ... from the directory contents
    $lowest_index++ while grep { $lowest_index == num( $_ ) } readdir $dirhandle;
    return $lowest_index;
}

# Ready to use!

my $index = min_index ( 'some/dir' , qr/^new project/ );

my $new_project_name = "new project $index";
```

Comment: LOL! my code looks like C compared to yours! :D Thanks for that, I will give it a try and try to understand how it works!

Comment: This finds the minimum index in use and adds one.  Suppose that 'new project 2' and 'new project 3' exist; won't this return 3, which is not available? Shouldn't it be returning 1 anyway?

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, I still have to try out this code but what my code does actually is finding the first available slot, so in your example project 1.

Comment: Is `rewinddir` needed?  Is scanning the directory twice a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# get the current list of files
# see `perldoc -f glob` for details.
my @files = glob( 'some/dir/new\\ project*' );

# set to first name, in case there are none others
my $next_file = 'new project1';

# check for others
if( @files ){

  # a Schwartian transform
  @files = map  { $_->[0]                                     }  # get original
           sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]                         }  # sort by second field which are numbers
           map  { [ $_, do{ ( my $n = $_ ) =~ s/\D//g; $n } ] }  # create an anonymous array with original value and the second field nothing but digits
           @files;

  # last file name is the biggest
  $next_file = $files[-1];

  # add one to it
  $next_file =~ s/(.*)(\d+)$/$1.($2+1)/e;
}

print "next file: $next_file\n";
```

Comment: Getting the biggest number and adding one is sane, but it is not what the question asked for.